# how does human brain compare to a modern CPU in energy per bit?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, computational-physics

Can someone compare the energy efficiency of human brain as a computer ? What is the energy in joules / flop ? may be some reasonable assumptions on the computational load of common tasks such as pattern recognition or speech synthesis can be used.

Comment: Related (not a duplicate): http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2178/how-efficient-is-a-desktop-computer

Comment: The human brain doesn't use bits

Comment: @David that was a very useful link !

Comment: This depends significantly on the task. Computers are much better at number crunching, but humans are much better at pattern recognition. (e.g. computers have trouble playing Go: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Go)

Comment: @blah Oh, how times have changed.

Answer (score 7):

Human power consumption [can be guesstimated](http://hypertextbook.com/facts/2001/JacquelineLing.shtml) as 100W, similar to the power consumption of an ordinary computer, plus or minus a few orders of magnitude depending on one's idea of "ordinary".  A computer can do billions of flops per second, and it would take me many seconds or minutes to perform one with pen and paper, and furthermore I will make many more errors.  If we assume that there is some other task which is stacked the opposite way, i.e. a human can perform it a billion times faster than a computer, and that both of these are in some sense extreme cases, then given some more "fair" test we can say that ratio of the efficiency is probably somewhere between $10^{-9}$ and $10^9$.

Comment: "somewhere between 10^−9 and 10^9" - a theoretical physicst at work!

Comment: is the 100W a maximum? because it would mean already 2000kcal power consumption a day just by the brain, and I guess this would make every girl happy (just kidding) but seriously speaking what is the power consumption for lazy activities like watching TV compared to doing math or theoretical physics.

Comment: @Marcel: Total brain activity doesn't change much with activity: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brain#Brain_energy_consumption REM sleep is the same as waking, although deep sleep is 25% lower: Drummond, "Functional imaging of the sleeping brain: review of findings and implications for the study of insomnia" Yes, the brain is an extremely energy-hungry device, but Dan's link actually gives the power as 20 W, not 100 W. I think Dan just called it 100 W because we're doing order-of-magnitude estimates. Obviously the brain can't burn 2000 kcal/day :-)

Comment: @Ben thank you. But also 20W is still a lot... nice to have some idea of the magnitude

Comment: 100W is a figure commonly used in A/C design. That's the total heat output of a human awake and at rest, rounded to a nice figure for engineering purposes. 20W sounds about right for the proportion used by the brain.

Answer (score 6):

The brain is massively parallel, so it tends to come out looking very good. The OP suggested using joules/flop as the measure of (in)efficiency. This leaves considerable ambiguity. I believe the way neurons typically work is that they form something like a weighted average of their binary inputs, and generate a binary output that is based on a threshold value for that average. I would consider this to be the moral equivalent of a floating-point operation. Of course if a floating-point operation means working out a long-division problem using paper and pencil, then the result is going to be horrible -- a kilojoule per flop for me, or infinitely many joules per flop for a kindergartener who hasn't yet learned the long division algorithm. To me it seems perverse to say that a kindergartener's brain has zero efficiency compared to an x86, so I'm going to equate one neuron's weighted-average operation to one flop.

I'm not a big fan of Ray Kurzweil, but he does have a good summary of some relevant data in his 2005 book The Singularity is Near. There's a lot of ambiguity in trying to estimate the number of fundamental operations involved in a certain neurological process. Kurzweil refers to "synaptic transactions," and equates one of those to be something like $10^3$ "arithmetic" operations, where I imagine that he means something roughly similar to my definition of an arithmetic operation above. Anyway, subject to all these ambiguities, the studies he cites estimates of $10^{14}$-$10^{19}$ Hz for the rate of operations per second. If the brain draws ~10 W (Dan's link says 20), then this is an energy consumption of $10^{-13}$-$10^{-18}$ joules per operation. Since a desktop computer currently does $\sim10^9$ arithmetic operations per second, this makes the brain more efficient, as measured by joules per operation, by about a factor of $10^6$-$10^{10}$.